# Using VBA to create a formula that changes based on checkboxes ticked

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to create a function where if a number of checkboxes are ticked in a userform, then the formula in cell A1 shows a different formula with a Choose function.

The formula that I want to appear if all boxes are selected is:

> =choose(randbetween(1,4),A3,A4,A5,A6)

If only certain boxes are selected e.g. boxes 1 and 3 are selected then the formula would be:

> =choose(randbetween(1,4),A3,B1,A5,B1)

Where B1 is a reference to a blank cell. 
The next formula would be dependent on the value of this cell.

Currently the approach I am taking is to do:

```
   Dim a as range, b as range, c as range, d as range,
   'set cell reference with data in if checkbox is selected, blank cell reference if checkbox not selected
   If checkbox1.value=TRUE then 
   set a = range("A3")
   else
   set a = range("B1")
   end if
   'this is repeated for all checkboxes
```

Next I want to have it so the formula in A1 is

> =choose(randbetween(1,4),a,b,c,d)

where a,b,c,d are the range that I have determined in the IF functions. This is where I am stuck. If I do

```
   [A1]="=choose(randbetween(1,4),a,b,c,d)"
```

Then the formula doesn't pick up on the values

If I do:

```
    Dim LValue As String
    LValue = Choose(Application.RandBetween(1, 4), a, b, c, d)
    [A1] = LValue
```

Then all that is returned is the value rather A1 having a formula within.

Any ideas?

Update:

Thank you for your suggestions. Inspiration struck after responding to your answers and the formula I needed was:

```
[A1] = "=choose(randbetween(1,4), " & a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & ")"
```

Which displays the formula in the cell with the variables changing. The variables had to be a string rather than a range too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to delete the comma after `d as range,`.
Then you need to add double quotations around the text you paste into the formula.

```
  [a1].Formula = "=choose(randbetween(1,4)," & Chr(34) & a & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & b & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & c & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & d & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue here as I need the entry in A1 to be the formula itself, not the result. This function still comes up with 'A3' rather than displaying the formula

Comment: so you want it to show the result in A1 but when you press on the cell, it should contain the formula as well?

Comment: Well see the updated answer. I believe you need "quotationmarks" around the a,b,c,d values when they are posted into a formula otherwise you'll probably get the `#NAME?` error.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it so abcd etc as string. a = "A3" and it seems to work without additional quotation marks. Everytime I tried double quotation marks I would get an error. What does Chr(34) mean in your formula?

Comment: I would bind the values as a `String` as well, but I guess it doesn´t really matter in this case, as `Range` also work. The `Chr(34)` is the Ascii for " (double quotation mark). You will get an error if you try to add quotation marks yourself, but this will do the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked :-) Please accept it as an answer, if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. Inspiration struck after responding to your answers and the formula I needed was:

```
    [A1] = "=choose(randbetween(1,4), " & a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & ")"
```

Which displays the formula in the cell with the variables changing. The variables had to be a string rather than a range too.